# Rotate tabindex through html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a PHP-generated form  that is used as an invoicing interface. Users work their way through the form by pressing `tab`. I need to rotate the tab key through the form until they finalize the invoicing process.

For example, with this form:

```
 <form>

 <input type = "text" name="a" tabindex=1>
 <input type = "text" name="b" tabindex=2>
 <input type = "text" name="c" tabindex=3>
 <input type = "text" name="d" tabindex=4>
 <input type = "text" name="e" tabindex=5> 
 <input type = "text" name="f" tabindex=6>
 <input type = "button" name="g" tabindex=7>

 <input type = "submit" name="h" tabindex=8>

 </form>
```

I need to move the tab index from 1 to 7, and then tab should move them back to field a. It needs to rotate and I need to move cursor to h when I press ESC.

Example -

**TAB Key moved the cursor from a->b->c->d->e->f->g->a->b->......->g**

**ESC Key Just move the Cursor to h**

How can I do this in HTML or javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used id instead of names. Guess this helps:

```
 <form>
     <input type = "text" id="a" tabindex=1/>
     <input type = "text" id="b" tabindex=2/>
     <input type = "text" id="c" tabindex=3/>
     <input type = "text" id="d" tabindex=4/>
     <input type = "text" id="e" tabindex=5/> 
     <input type = "text" id="f" tabindex=6/>
     <input type = "button" id="g" value="next" tabindex=7/>
     <input type = "submit" id="h" value="ok" tabindex=8/>
 </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 9 && $(event.target).is('#g') ){
            $('#a').focus(); 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 27){
            $('#h').focus(); 
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to this question and get success.

```
   <script> 
   window.history.forward(1); 
   document.attachEvent("onkeydown", my_onkeydown_handler); 
   function my_onkeydown_handler() 
   { 
   switch (event.keyCode) 
   { 

   case 9 :
   document.form.a.focus();
   event.keyCode = 0;
   break;

   case 27 :
   document.form.h.focus();
   event.keyCode = 0;
   break;
   } 
   } 
   </script>
```